# Asp.net signalR onclose is getting called only once

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'm using asp.net signalr in my application. I'm doing manual reconnect. It's reconnecting first time when it's disconnected. I'm using onclose method to reconnect. But the onclose event is not getting called second time.

Below is my code.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/connectHub")
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
    }
};

connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});
```

The method "onclose" is calling when it's disconnected first time. When it disconnects second time it's not coming to "onclose" method, so reconnect also not happening.

Thanks

Comment: There's insufficient information to the question and in the provided code. How does it getting called? What is `getSignalrConnection()`?

Comment: Please provide more code so we can help you.

Comment: Hi. Updated my question